# After page refresh the value (css) of input is gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do have a select box, like so:

```
<select id="fatherhoodDocument" name="fatherhoodDocument" style="width:250px;" data-bvalidator="myCyrillicDigitsAndSpaceValidator,required" data-bvalidator-modifier="myCapsModifier">
                <option value="[$i18n.getString( "select" )]">[$i18n.getString( "select" )]</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test</option>
                <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

And I have 2 hidden inputs, which should be activated and shown if one of the options above have been chosen:

```
<input type="text" id="marriageregdate" name="marriageregdate" value="" style="width:80px; display:none;" data-bvalidator="required" data-fordraft="required"/>
<input type="text" id="filliationregdate" name="filliationregdate" value="" style="width:80px; display:none;" data-bvalidator="required" data-fordraft="required"/>
```

This is the `JavaScript` code which does change the properties, if some of the options have been clicked:

```
$('#fatherhoodDocument').on('change',function(){
                    var selection = $(this).val();
                    switch(selection){
                    case "test1":
                        $("#marriageregdate").show();
                        $( "#marriageregdate" ).prop( "disabled", false );
                        $("#filliationregdate").hide();
                        $( "#filliationregdate" ).prop( "disabled", true );
                    break;
                    case "test2":
                        $("#filliationregdate").show();
                        $( "#filliationregdate" ).prop( "disabled", false );
                        $("#marriageregdate").hide();
                        $( "#marriageregdate" ).prop( "disabled", true );
                    break;

                    default:
                    $("#marriageregdate").hide();
                    $("#filliationregdate").hide();

                    }
                });
```

It works just fine, untill the page has not been refreshed. Once the page is refresehed (clicked f5, or browser icon) the inputs go back to their original state, i.e hidden. But the value of the `select box` remains the same as it was chosen before.
So, my question is how to save the `code` changes too, after the page have been refreshed?

Comment: is the first option in the dropdown a default value like "Select" or something like that?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen, yes the default values will be [Select], depending on the language. but it will have these squares [] if it matters

Answer (score 1):

Well, on page load/refresh, `$('#fatherhoodDocument')` hasn't changed yet so the change handler isn't called. What you could do is assign the change handler to a variable and call that on document ready **and** on `$('#fatherhoodDocument')` change.

```
$(function () {
  var ddFatherhoodDocument = $('#fatherhoodDocument');
  var toggleTextboxes = function () {
    var selection = ddFatherhoodDocument.val();
    switch(selection) {
      case "test1":
        $("#marriageregdate").show();
        $( "#marriageregdate" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        $("#filliationregdate").hide();
        $( "#filliationregdate" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        break;
      case "test2":
        $("#filliationregdate").show();
        $( "#filliationregdate" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        $("#marriageregdate").hide();
        $( "#marriageregdate" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        break;
      default:
        $("#marriageregdate").hide();
        $("#filliationregdate").hide();
    }
  }

  ddFatherhoodDocument.on('change', toggleTextboxes);
  toggleTextboxes();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like as shown below,you can define the function under a different function name and call it on ready of the document as well as on change of the dropdown ,in the on ready function the changeData function will not be called unless the dropdown has something selected in it other than the default selection

```js
$('#fatherhoodDocument').on('change',changeData);
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log($("#fatherhoodDocument")[0].selectedIndex);
  
if($('#fatherhoodDocument')[0].selectedIndex!=0){
      changeData();
    }
});
function changeData(){
 var selection = $('#fatherhoodDocument').val();
 switch(selection){
 case "test1":                        $("#marriageregdate").show();
$( "#marriageregdate" ).prop( "disabled", false );                      $("#filliationregdate").hide();
$( "#filliationregdate" ).prop( "disabled", true );
break;
case "test2":                      $("#filliationregdate").show();
$( "#filliationregdate" ).prop( "disabled", false);                  $("#marriageregdate").hide();
$( "#marriageregdate" ).prop( "disabled", true );
break;
default:                  $("#marriageregdate").hide();               $("#filliationregdate").hide();
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fatherhoodDocument" name="fatherhoodDocument" style="width:250px;" data-bvalidator="myCyrillicDigitsAndSpaceValidator,required" data-bvalidator-modifier="myCapsModifier">
                <option value="[$i18n.getString( "select" )]">[$i18n.getString( "select" )]</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test</option>
                <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="marriageregdate" name="marriageregdate" value="" style="width:80px; display:none;" data-bvalidator="required" data-fordraft="required"/>
<input type="text" id="filliationregdate" name="filliationregdate" value="" style="width:80px; display:none;" data-bvalidator="required" data-fordraft="required"/>
```

Comment: the idea behind it is nice, however the code always returns 0, even if there are different value is selected in the select box. And I still have the same old issue

Comment: In this snippet it will happen like that ,but did you try it in your code ,because according to you the value in the select dropdown  remains at the value you selected even after refresh ,so the value of the selected Index will also change depending on the selection from the dropdown

Comment: yes, I can clearly see that the value on the screen remains the same, but console prints 0. Might be the issue is deeper

Comment: I have edited it ,now it will work,just try it and see

Comment: Oh i see.. still the same result

Comment: nope before the selection variable was obtained from "$(this).value" but that won't work when the function is called onload so i have replaced that with " $('#fatherhoodDocument').val()"

Answer (score 0):

I am not why your SELECT remains unchanged on page refresh. However if you want to keep very first option selected after page refresh just try to add "selected" attribute. check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp).

```html
<select id="fatherhoodDocument" name="fatherhoodDocument" style="width:250px;" data-bvalidator="myCyrillicDigitsAndSpaceValidator,required" data-bvalidator-modifier="myCapsModifier">
                <option value="[$i18n.getString( "select" )]" selected>[$i18n.getString( "select" )]</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test</option>
                <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```